# $XDG_CACHE_HOME vs. $XDG_STATE_HOME

Tags: environment-variables, directory-structure, xdg, xdg-user-dirs

[Based on the XDG Base Directory Spacifications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#:%7E:text=actions%20history%20(logs%2C%20history%2C%20recently%20used%20files%2C%20%E2%80%A6)), `$XDG_STATE_HOME` should store history and log of the programs. But it is very common to see UNIX programs storing these kind of stuff at `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`, that is, `$HOME/.cache`. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`XDG_STATE_HOME` isn’t used much because it’s a recent addition to the specification. [Version 0.7 of the specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/0.7/ar01s02.html) doesn’t mention it, it was added in version 0.8, published in May 2021.

In previous versions, `XDG_CACHE_HOME` was the most appropriate location for logs etc. since they arguably qualify as “non-essential”; but it wasn’t great, since they are not cached data.

You should use `$XDG_STATE_HOME` to store history and logs, and use `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` only for cached data.